# Add several individual threads to MQTT Python code

Tags: multithreading, python-multithreading, uart

this is my code and I need add,

(1) loop(thread1) which can publish data when receive specific data by UART(ser.read())

(2) loop(thread2) which can run report_temp_humidity() with timed delay

so I put thread for test but this runs only one time, not loop.

Is this cause by "mqttclient.loop_forever()" at the end of line?

Need some help on this.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import Adafruit_DHT
import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART
import serial
import threading
import time

# DHT-11 Temperature & Humidity
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11
sensor_pin = 'P8_11'

# UART
UART.setup("UART1")
ser = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyO1", baudrate=9600)
ser.close()
ser.open()

# Define event callbacks
def on_connect(self, client, userdata, rc):
        if rc == 0:
                print("Connected successfully.")
        else:
                print("Connection failed. rc= "+str(rc))

def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
        print("Message "+str(mid)+" published.")

def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):
        print("Subscribe with mid "+str(mid)+" received.")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print("Message received on topic "+msg.topic+" with QoS "+str(msg.qos)+"and payload "+msg.payload) 
        if msg.payload == "check_status":
            report_temp_humidity()
        if msg.payload == "motor_run!":
            print "Send command to RF"
            ser.write("11.1111[S]")

# Define my function prototypes
def report_temp_humidity():
        hum, temp = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, sensor_pin)
        mqttclient.publish("/my_topic1/", "Temperature "+ str(temp) + "`C", qos=0)
        mqttclient.publish("/my_topic1/", "Humidity " + str(hum) + "%", qos=0)

# Define thread(loop) test
def loop_test(delay):
        print(loop!)
        time.sleep(1)  

t1 = threading.Thread(target=loop_test, args=('1,',))
t1.start()


mqttclient = mqtt.Client()

# Assign event callbacks
mqttclient.on_connect = on_connect
mqttclient.on_publish = on_publish
mqttclient.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
mqttclient.on_message = on_message

# Connect
mqttclient.username_pw_set("dioty_user", "1234567")
mqttclient.connect("mqtt.dioty.co", 1883)

# Start subscription
mqttclient.subscribe("/my_topic1/")

# Publish a message
mqttclient.publish("/my_topic1/", "Hello World Message!")

# Loop
mqttclient.loop_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the MQTT library.

Your thread `t1` will run the `loop_test` function, which only has 2 statements in it. It will run these (once) then exit, there is nothing to tell it to continue to do anything else.

If you want that thread to continue to run for ever then you will need to include a loop statement of some sort (e.g. `while True`).